@SpringBootTest: @ActiveProfiles doesn't work when put on @Nested inner class
I have a spring boot app.
project deps (plugins section):

id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.1'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'

And I want to test on of my services that works differently based on some properties.
I have separated set of properties and its values in different profiles, e.g. profile-1 and profile-2. Corresponding application-profile-1.yml and application-profile-2 and placed under src/test/resources.
Let's say I am trying to test the service behaviour based on:
reporting:
  view:
    mode: <value>

where <value> can be short, full or custom
This is my config that fails:
@SpringBootTest
public OuterTestClass {

    @SpyBean
    SomeDependency someDependency;

    @Autowired
    TypeUnderTest subject;

    @Nested
    @ActiveProfiles("profile-1")
    public class Profile1Tests {

        @Test 
        public void test1() {
            subject.method();
            // verifications
        }

    }

    @Nested
    @ActiveProfiles("profile-2")
    public class Profile2Tests {

        @Test 
        public void test2() {
            subject.method();
            // verifications
        }

    }

}

Execution throws common java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext ... exception because my beans could not be instantiated with null properties.
It seems to me that the root cause is that @ActiveProfiles is not supported on @Nested classes but outer only. It this a right assumption?
Actually what my goal is to avoid spamming enormous amount of standalone test classes with respective @ActiveProfiles applied on them for readability reasons.
I've also tried to apply @TestPropertySource on the nested classes and it doesn't work as well.
Seeking for advises on my case.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440525/how-to-add-inner-classes-to-spring-application-context-for-unit-testing

Thanks @Alan Hay for the reference. However that is kinda different problem, I don't use any explicit configurations, I want load original context as it is.
